# AngularJS, cannot access $scope.variableName

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-http

I am new to AngularJS and having an strange problem, that I can't access to `$scope.name`. In the factory `DataService` I have a method `getData()` which uses $http.get(...).

```
angular.module("app", []).factory("DataService", function($q, $http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getData = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(apiPath).success(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            deferred.reject('Error: ' + status);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return service;
}).controller("DataController", ["$scope", "DataService", function($scope, DataService) {
    $scope.datas = [];
    DataService.getData().then(function(data){
        $scope.datas = data;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
    console.log($scope.datas); // it returns []
}]);
```

I can't understand why it returns an empty array.

Comment: When you call .then() you are resolving an async promise. You are logging to console before your data is actually assigned to the variable.

Comment: How can I resolve that problem please?

Comment: Move the console.log into the .then() function.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. But outside of the .then() block I cannot access the returned data, right? I actually want to get the data out of the block.

Comment: You can access it, once the promise is resolved. For example, if that scope variable is in a data bind in a view somewhere {{ datas }}, then when the promise is resolved and you do the data assignment, angular will update the scope and it will show up in the view. Usually you will want to save the data from your $http calls in a service. And have the controllers call functions in the service to retrieve data. The view bindings will update automatically :)

Comment: Thanks aet! Yes, I can access that data within .then() block. Could you please make a short example how we can do in Service?